# Run async action method in background

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous

Is there any way to call async action method in standard action method and not wait for the async method execution (keeping the same Request object)?

```
public class StandardController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Save()
    {
        // call Background.Save, do not wait for it and go to the next line

        return View();
    }
}

public class BackgroundController : AsyncController
{
    public void SaveAsync()
    {
        // background work
    }
}
```

I've tried to use Task class to do the backround work, but when I was starting the task and the action method has returned the View, the Request was killed and my DependencyResolver instance was erased, so the background task started to throw exceptions.

The first idea was to execute the Standard.Save (without calling the background task) and return the View in which the Background.Save method could be called in ajax. So in other words: call the another request to the async controller, to start the background task.

The main problem is how to call the async method keeping the authorization information (in cookies) and dependency resolver (in my case: autofac).

Comment: Why are you directly calling methods of a controller to begin with?

Comment: You can just call it. `SaveAsync()` will return the control to `Save()` on the first `await` statement if it has to wait. If you want to use a background thread, use `Task.Run()`

Comment: Just realized that `SaveAsync` is not async. Either make it async or call it using `Task.Run()`

Comment: Ok, Task.Run() will start the task, but when the line "return View();" is executed, the Request is going to dispose and the background task will have no access to the dependency resolver and request context.

Comment: I guess your problem is similar as the one in this related question  http://stackoverflow.com/q/12319642/1236044

Comment: @jbl, yes, that's exactly the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can run some async method in sync code:

```
public class StandardController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Save()
    {
        //code...
        YourMethod();
        //code...
        return View();
    }
    public async void YourMethod()
    {
      await Task.Run(()=>{
      //your async code...
      });
    }
}
```

YourMethod() will be going before and after Save() is fully performed.

Answer (score -1):

For me this is working great:

```
    public class PartnerController : Controller
    {
    public ActionResult Registration()
    {
        var model = new PartnerAdditional();
        model.ValidFrom = DateTime.Today;
        new Action<System.Web.HttpRequestBase>(MyAsync).BeginInvoke(this.HttpContext.Request, null, null);
        return View(model);
    }

    private void MyAsync(System.Web.HttpRequestBase req)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        foreach (var item in req.Cookies)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

The Page is posted back and aroud 10 seconds later Async appears in my Debug Output. 
Not sure how this would work with Cookies/Authentication infos but in doubt you can pass the values to the method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You're not accessing the request information from the background task; just writing to the debug console, which is why it works.  If the background task needs to access the request information (even to read from it; assuming it doesn't write to the response) this won't work.

Comment: Of course i assume that he doesnt want to modify the request in the Async method. <br/> "If the background task needs to access the request information (even to read from it; assuming it doesn't write to the response) this won't work." He can also pass the httpContext.Request and read from it, it wont dispose.

Comment: He doesn't need to modify it, but he needs access to it.  To quote the question, `"The main problem is how to call the async method keeping the authorization information (in cookies) and dependency resolver (in my case: autofac)."`  This doesn't address that at all.

Comment: Edited the Templated to show that i can Access (for example) the cookies of the Request in the background thread.